# A good reference for learning about super-differentiation & super-integration?

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, manifolds, superalgebra

I've looked at a couple of books for basic information for super-differentiation & super-integration - Rogers *Supermanifolds*, and Khrennikovs *Superanalysis*.

Unfortunately both books lack a clear set of simple examples to build up some basic intuition about these operations. Is there a good basic reference for these ideas, are they more likely found in the physics literature?

For example:

a. what exactly is the difference between left & right differentiation, and how are they related.

b. Does this mean that there is a left & right integration too?

c. What are the rules for super-differentiating & integrating polynomials?

d. Are there analogues of sin, cos, exp & ln for super-functions?